# SSRS 2008 R2 returns "#ERROR" when exporting to PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, switch-statement

I am attempting to parse a string that contains a device's make, model, and serial number into separate fields to end up in their own column in the report.

The source value would generally be something like `3B0645X01543 APCBack-UPS ES 550 FW:840.B2.D USB FW:B2` where the first set of characters is the serial number, APC is the make, and `Back-UPS ES 550` is the model.  My goal is to have my report return a value of "APC" for make, the number value after ES for model, and the first character set for serial number.  I have this working as long as I render directly to HTML. If I render to PDF, Excel, or anything else each of these columns return `#Error`.  Here is how I'm doing it.

The source is a field in the same data set named `DeviceID`.  For the example, it contains the string `3B0645X01543 APCBack-UPS ES 550 FW:840.B2.D USB FW:B2`.

I have 3 calculated fields in my dataset, Make, Model, and Serial. The expression for Make is below.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!DeviceID.Value.ToString().Contains("EATON"), "Eaton", Fields!DeviceID.Value.ToString().Contains("APC"), "APC", Fields!DeviceID.Value.ToString().Contains("Tripp"), "TrippLite", Fields!DeviceID.Value.ToString().Contains("American"), "APC")
```

I am then using a lookup function to pull this `Make` field into the table in my report.

Again, if I render to HTML all three values work like a champ. Any other render gets me `#Error`.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate this with the version I have available (SQL 2012) but I could not reproduce the issue. A bit of research on Google showed this same issue has occurred for others and seems to be related to using the Lookup function in some situations, but I did not find a solution.

However I can suggest a workaround to try:

Instead of adding calculated fields to your dataset, add some custom code to the report to parse the DeviceID. For example to get the Make, you could use something like this (apologies there is probably a much more elegant way of doing this):

```
 Public Function DeviceIDMake(ByVal DeviceID As String) As String
        If  DeviceID.ToString().Contains("EATON") Then
            Return "Eaton"
        Else
            If DeviceID.ToString().Contains("APC") Then
    Return "APC"
            Else 
    If DeviceID.ToString().Contains("Tripp") Then
        Return "TrippLite"
                Else 
       If DeviceID.ToString().Contains("American") Then
           Return "APC"
                   Else 
          Return ""
                   End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
 End Function
```

Then in your report, you can call the code like so to get the "Make":

```
=Code.DeviceIDMake(Fields!DeviceID.Value)
```

This might avoid whatever is causing your rendering issue.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thanks for your help!  Sorry for the long delay.  Unfortunately, I only get to work on this project before daylight on Tuesdays.  This worked much better and runs considerably faster than using calculated fields as well.

For others interested, in my case I still had to use the LOOKUP function to pull the code into my report since the table is of a different dataset.